# How to add default headers to each mailer rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to add default headers to each mailer. I have a helper where I create the header but I still need to call the helper (`add_headers`) in each mailer seperatly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that [`default`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#edit-the-mailer) works for headers too:

```
class ApplicationMailer
  default headers: { foo: 'bar' }
end

def BazMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # ...
end
```